# How do I make chroot run a command in the same directory in the new rootfs as I am in now?

Tags: shell, variables, quoting, chroot

I have various other Linux distros on other partitions and am trying to write a command called "on" that will run a shell command in that distro as the same user and in the same directory as I am in on the host filesystem in a way that preserves arguments containing spaces or wildcard characters.

I have got as far as

```
#! /bin/sh
# on: Run a command as the same user in the same directory inside a chroot
# Usage: on directory command [args]
chrootdir="$1"
shift
sudo chroot --userspec="`whoami`" "$chrootdir" sh -c "cd \"`pwd`\" && $@"
```

which will run it as the same user in the same dir, but would fail if there are spaces in the arguments (or the comnand name!).

One solution is a cd-ing wrapper script:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Run a command in a specified directory
# Usage: runin dir command [args]
cd "$1" && shift && cmd="$2" && shift && exec "$cmd" "$@"
```

called by

```
#! /bin/sh
# on: Run a command as the same user in the same directory inside a chroot
# Usage: on directory command [args]
chrootdir="$1"
shift
sudo chroot --userspec="`whoami`" "$chrootdir" runin "`pwd`" "$@"
```

but the wrapper has to exist in all the chroot environments, which is boring.

Is there a way to make a single command on the host system that makes the "cd" happen in the chroot, correctly preserving all arguments?

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the script and pass the arguments like you do in your script:

```
sudo chroot --userspec="$(id -u):$(id -g)" "$1" \
     sh -c 'cd "$1" && shift && exec "$@"' -- "$(pwd)" "$@"
```

Notes:

- sudo is odd there in script
- I do not think whoami is in POSIX. I think id is more portable.
- Prefer `$(...)` over backticks
- Do not quote yourself `\"`pwd"`. If you want to quote something, use` printf "%q"`. In this case, pass as parameter and properly quote inside subshell` sh -c 'echo "$1"' -- "$(pwd)"`

Comment: ```$ on /mnt/sda9 ls /``` gives me ```--: 1: exec: /mnt/sda9: not found```

Comment: However, your mechanism is right (thanks!). It just needs ```shift 2```, not sure why. If you edit it, I'll boost you.